# Android SMS gateway app

Tags: android, http, sms

I would like to send and receive SMS from my application, preferably using an android phone.

I am currently using the app [SMS gateway](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.apksoft.android.smsgateway) by b00lean, but when it sends messages it requests a receipt which my service provider bill me extra for.

I want to send and receive messages using HTTP requests on the local network, not via any cloud service.
I have checked some apps, but many of them is communicating through a cloud service or don't have the possibility to send SMS directly via an HTTP request.

Anyone know an app which may work?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the author or get the source code and remove the problematic code

Comment: I tried to send him an email now, but the e-mail adress provided on google play is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The Android Messages app supports this functionality:

[image: Android Messages]

**References**

- [Send and receive text messages (SMS & MMS) with Android Messages - Project Fi Help](https://support.google.com/fi/answer/6205096?hl=en)
- [Android Messages - Apps on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging)